# When vs If - Word-Usage

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

I know I can substitute "if" with "when", but, I think there's a different meaning here:

> If you're ready to learn it, you know where to find me (0 cond)
>
> When you're ready to learn it, you know where to find me (maybe something else?)

Could guys explain me why these sentences are different from each other in meaning? Thanks in advance

Comment: [Could you explain **to me** why etc.]. And frankly, I think **when** and **if** are different in most languages. So,what is the point of your question??

Comment: Hello Lambie. Well, I've searched about Conditionals and I've seen that If and When can be used interchangeably sometimes. That's why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **If you are ready to learn, you know where to find me.**
>
> **When you are ready to learn, you know where to find me**

I think **If you are ready to learn**talks about the present state( If he is ready or not ready)

The speaker thinks that he might be ready  to learn now.

**When you are ready to learn** means that the speaker thinks that he is not ready to learn now but he will be ready to learn in the future.